# Prefix img source url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cross-domain

My application is distributed on 3 servers :

- the client code provider (port 4000)
- the REST server (port 3000)
- the image provider (port 3001)

I am using BackboneJS for client code.

**Is there a way to prefix every relative image url** with javascript as is it possible for ajax request with :

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.url = 'http://localhost:3000' + options.url;
});
```

so that I could have something like :

```
<img src="items/1.png">  //get it on http://localhost:3001  instead of default http://localhost:4000
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the img element where you want to prefix the links? If this is the case, are you using templates?

Comment: Yeh sure I am using templates and I could for each image tag add the prefix on each view. But I hoped there was something like for ajax requests to prefix every requets without doing anything.

Comment: Try using regexp:                              `$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) { options.url = "http://localhost:" +  ((options.url.search(/\.png|\.jpg/i) == -1) ? 3000 : 3001) + options.url; }`

Comment: This will not work : for now the browser is trying to get the image on the client code provider (4000) which show that images requests are not handle by $.ajaxPrefilter()

Comment: nether mind, I will modify the image url when I get it from the REST server.